# Google Cloud DNS for Google Domain but for Subdomain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

My domain (on Google domains) has published custom NS records that match a Google Cloud DNS zone. This domain `example.com` has DNSSEC on which is published in Google Domains along with the NS records (in the custom DNS section). I also have a subdomain `beta.example.com` that I would like to distinguish in a separate Cloud DNS zone where I conduct my **"beta"** testing.

The problem is, Google Domains only allows me to create custom NS records and DNSSEC for `example.com` but not for my subdomain `beta.example.com`.

Is there anyway to create two unique Cloud DNS zones on Google Cloud: one for `example.com` and one for `beta.example.com`?

They can share the NS and DNSSEC, but I just want them in two different zones so that I don't have all the **"beta"** records with the non-beta ones.

But when the zone is created, a unique NS record set and DNSSEC which I can't add (customize) for a subdomain in Google Domains.

Do I have a solution or do I have to maintain all the beta records with the non-beta records?

**Details:**

Two domains: **example.com** and **beta.example.com**

Two DNS zones: **website DNS** and **website-beta DNS**

**website DNS:**

[image]

*Along with unique **SOA** record and **DS***

**website-beta DNS**

[image]

*Along with unique **SOA** record and **DS***

**Google Domains:**

[image]

**Problem:** When I add additional NS and DS records (Google Domains), it doesn't do anything. It only counts the first records. There is no way to add custom name servers for subdomains.

The only solution I see is put everything under one DNS zone. OR not use the Cloud DNS records and instead use the ones that Google Domain provides (or something like that)

Comment: Both my domain and subdomain are on two zones with DNSSEC. Do I change the subdomain to direct to NS for the domain?

Comment: Hi \`Maciek Semik\` can you check this \[blog\](https://articles.wesionary.team/configure-gcp-cloud-dns-for-custom-domains-and-subdomains-609983afe39d) written by \*\*Sujal Dulai\*\*, he has detailed on how to configure different zones for custom domains and sub domains in cloud dns.<br>

Comment: Hi `Maciek Semik` is your issue resolved, if you are sill facing some issues revert back here so that we can assist you..